# Convert dictionary of sets to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary of sets in python, something like:

```
{'+++': {'---', '--0', '-00', '0--', '00-', '000'}, '0++': {'+--', '+0-', '---', '--0', '-00', '0--', '00-', '000'}}
```

and I want to convert this into a pandas dictionary, with two columns: the first being the indices of the dictionary and the 2nd, being the set of strings. When I try to do this with Dataframe.from_dict, pandas creates as many columns as the max number of strings in a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should surround your value in dict by list.

```
import pandas as pd
test_dict = {
    "+++": {"---", "--0", "-00", "0--", "00-", "000"},
    "0++": {"+--", "+0-", "---", "--0", "-00", "0--", "00-", "000"},
}
for key, value in test_dict.items():
    test_dict[key] = [value]
print(test_dict)
```

then your dict change to this:

```
{
    "+++": [{"00-", "-00", "---", "0--", "--0", "000"}],
    "0++": [{"00-", "-00", "---", "+--", "0--", "+0-", "--0", "000"}],
}
```

last, use from_dict:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test_dict, orient="index").reset_index()
print(test_df)
```

this is the result.

```
index                                         0
0   +++            {00-, -00, ---, 0--, --0, 000}
1   0++  {00-, -00, ---, +--, 0--, +0-, --0, 000}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do `explode`, `d` is your dict here

```
#d = {'+++': {'---', '--0', '-00', '0--', '00-', '000'}, '0++': {'+--', '+0-', '---', '--0', '-00', '0--', '00-', '000'}}
out = pd.Series(d).explode().reset_index(name='value')
Out[306]: 
   index value
0    +++   ---
1    +++   00-
2    +++   -00
3    +++   000
4    +++   --0
5    +++   0--
6    0++   ---
7    0++   +0-
8    0++   +--
9    0++   00-
10   0++   -00
11   0++   000
12   0++   --0
13   0++   0--
```

Or just

```
pd.Series(d).reset_index(name='value')
Out[310]: 
  index                                     value
0   +++            {---, 00-, -00, 000, --0, 0--}
1   0++  {---, +0-, +--, 00-, -00, 000, --0, 0--}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the set to remain whole, you can try:

```
data = {'+++': {'---', '--0', '-00', '0--', '00-', '000'}, '0++': {'+--', '+0-', '---', '--0', '-00', '0--', '00-', '000'}}

pd.DataFrame([data.keys(), data.values()]).T

     0                                         1
0  +++            {--0, -00, ---, 00-, 0--, 000}
1  0++  {--0, -00, +--, ---, 00-, 0--, 000, +0-}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine manually mapping your keys and values to specific columns would be suitable for your problem.

```
a = {'+++': {'---', '--0', '-00', '0--', '00-', '000'}, '0++': {'+--', '+0-', '---', '--0', '-00', '0--', '00-', '000'}}

pd.DataFrame({'key': a.keys(), 'value': a.values()})
```